# Make a loop faster

Tags: matlab

I have a for loop as part of my code. `N` could be very large (may be about `10^8`). Is there any way to make it faster? `needed` and `choose_set` are `23*1` and `33*8` respectively.

```
             pos = VChooseK(1:ss,i);
             N = size(pos);
             N=N(1);
             for j = 1 : N,
                testset=unique(choose_set(pos(j,:)',:));
                if sum(size(setdiff(needed,testset))) < 2,
                    no_solution = 0;
                    solution =pos(j,:);
                end
            end
```

Comment: You haven't defined what `pos` is.

Comment: @krisdestruction: It is added to the code

Comment: Right, but I still can't generate values for it. I got a better idea, perhaps you could post what pos could be? I'm simulating `needed` and `choose_set` to be `randn` matricies.

Comment: @krisdestruction: `pos` is a matrix of the `size(N,M)`. `M` is less than '10', but as described in the question, `N` could be very large.

Comment: Are `pos` elements constrained within some range?

Comment: @krisdestruction: They are changed from `1` to `size(choose_set,1)`.

Comment: So using `ceil( rand(N,M) * size(choose_set,1) )` should correctly simulate values?

Comment: Elements of `pos` are not random. They are made using `Vchoosek` or `Nchoosek` command.

Comment: I realize that, but that then depends on your data/parameters. I meant would it work as a toy example for performance testing if I used that line of code. Unless you're willing to upload that for me to check.

Comment: Nevermind, I'll just choose values for `ss` and `i`

Comment: Please check my answer, we can look into it further from there

Answer (score 1):

After running with `N = 1e4` on the code below you can see my results from the code profiler.

```
N = 1e4;
M = 10;
needed = randn(23,1);
choose_set = randn(33,8);
pos = ceil( rand(N,M) * size(choose_set,1) );

for j = 1 : N
    testset = unique( choose_set( pos(j,:)', : ) );
    if sum( size( setdiff( needed, testset ) ) ) < 2
        no_solution = 0;
        solution = pos(j,:);
    end
end
```

The code profiler shows that `setdiff` takes 18% of the time while `unique` takes 51%. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve with your code but these are the two functions slowing your code down. To optimize this, you need to vectorize your code accordingly.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8cOqp6w.png]

Comment: I'm still trying to see if I can get a solution to use `cellfun` or `parfor` to vectorize/optimize your code but that will have to wait until the morning. I'm not sure if there's a better way than using `unique` and `setdiff`.

Comment: I used below code instead of using`unique`. But it need too memory for large `N`.

Comment: `PO=pos';
           PP=PO(:);
           choose1=choose_set(PP',:);
           S1=size(pos,2);
           C1=size(choose_set,2);
           choose2=(reshape (choose1',S1*C1,[]))';
           choose3 = sort(choose2,2).' ;
           d1 = [true(1,size(choose3,2)) ; diff(choose3)>0] ;
           testset= (choose3.*d1)';% unique values in each rows of choose2`

Comment: `   neededr = repmat (needed' , size( testset , 1) , 1);
           neededr_testset = [neededr,testset];
               neededr_testset1 = sort(neededr_testset,2).' ;
           d2 = [true(1,size(neededr_testset1,2)) ; diff(neededr_testset1)>0] ;
           neededr_testset2 = (neededr_testset1.*d2)';% unique values in each rows of neededr_testset
           neededr_testset3 = neededr_testset2 ( : , 1 : size ( neededr , 2 ));`

Comment: `           neededr_testset4 = sum(neededr_testset3 ~=0 , 2);%number of non-zero elements in each row of neededr_testset3
           neededr_testset5 = find ( neededr_testset4 < 2);
           
           size (neededr_testset5 , 1)
           if size (neededr_testset5 , 1) > 0
               j = max (neededr_testset5 , 1);
               no_solution = 0;
               solution =pos(j,:);
           end`

Comment: That's quite unreadable. Perhaps you can pastebin it? As for memory, this assumes you have enough memory to run the program. If not, you'll have to batch the processing and save it to file or get a computer that can run the script entirely. By optimize, I thought you meant faster which is what you said in your original question.

Comment: @Meher81 Wait if you're doing a `setdiff` anyways, why do you need `unique` ? A `setdiff` should already account for any duplicates right? Can  you test without using `unique`?

Comment: @Meher81 If I were to hazard a guess, you're simply storing too many variables with your sort+diff method. Try doing 1-liners instead.